# Erro com deploy de Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```
api.min.js:2 GET https://api.opmnstr.com/v1/optin/13439/673828 410
(anonymous) @ api.min.js:2
Ye.send @ api.min.js:2
getCampaigns @ api.min.js:2
t.init @ api.min.js:2
o.onload.o.onreadystatechange @ pag:180
load (async)
(anonymous) @ pag:180
(anonymous) @ pag:180
api.min.js:2 [OptinMonster] The campaign could not be retrieved. The following error was returned: A campaign with the ID 673828 does not exist.
```

Essa é a mensagem de erro que aparece no console quando atualizo a página, pois bem, usei o "npm run build" pra criar uma versão pra fazer o deploy no 000webhost, fiz o upload dos arquivos e abri o link, até ai tudo certo, navega entre páginas e tudo, o problema é ao abrir diretamente a url da página, da erro, se for usando os botões o site navega, mas ao atualizar da erro e diz que a página não existe.
**example.com** assim funciona, e se clicar pra ir pra página 1 ele vai
**example.com/pagina1** porém assim, o site não acha a página

**Edit 1:**
Vue router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import pagina from '@/components/pagina'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    }, {
      path: '/pag',
      name: 'pagina',
      component: pagina
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Está usando o router? Se possível poste ele, que só com essa informação so da para saber que o OptinMonster tem algum problema

Comment: Acabei de editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que era um problema com o servidor, ele não estava reconhecendo a configuração.

Então procurei no vuejs docs e achei algo que resolveu.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Era isso que eu queria ver, se você tem o HTML5 History Mode habilitado você tem que redirecionar todas as requisições para o index.html